# Not All Messages Forwarded to SQS from GetStream.io

Tags: amazon-sqs, getstream-io

**Setup:** A flat feed (representing an artist) is followed by another flat feed (representing users). Activities are added to the artist feed and the expectation is that those activities show on the feeds of all users following an artist and are then forwarded to a queue in AWS SQS.

**Problem:** The problem is that not all messages are appearing in SQS. We have extensive logging in place and never see some messages show either in the queue or lambda which consumes the queue. This functionality was working last week (2020-04-22) without any code changes in the meantime.

**Debugging Notes:**

- Activities show in the artist and user feeds in the GetStream.io dashboard but not SQS
- "Test SQS" button in GetStream.io dashboard generates a success message and the test message is visible in the queue and consuming lambda
- Some messages are forwarded to SQS while others are not

**Decoded sample message that did get through to SQS:**

```
{'new': [{'actor': '30026dd3-c557-46a0-b1c3-20b6e2dc5e2d', 'foreign_id': 'social_spike_twitter:GlobalParticipant_30026dd3-c557-46a0-b1c3-20b6e2dc5e2d', 'id': '37114000-7f75-11ea-8080-8000273a69c4', 'object': '{"new_followers":100}', 'origin': 'participant_spike:GlobalParticipant_30026dd3-c557-46a0-b1c3-20b6e2dc5e2d', 'target': '', 'time': '2020-04-16T00:00:00.000000', 'verb': 'social_spike_twitter'}], 'deleted': [], 'deleted_foreign_ids': [], 'feed': 'user_mobile_push:ArtistProfile_19', 'app_id': 39400, 'published_at': '2020-04-22T18:11:58.160Z'}
```